# Custom Layout for Collection view doesn't update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am using the following code in order to have a `UICollectionView` with variable height for various cells:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return totalItems
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        totalItems -= 1

        collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}

extension InviteViewController : PinterestLayoutDelegate {

    // 1. Returns the cell height
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        print("have: ", indexPath.item)
        if(indexPath.item % 3 == 0) {
            return 150
        } else if(indexPath.item % 3 == 1) {
            return 200
        } else {
            return 250
        }
    }
}
```

However I see that the layout doesn't update after the deletion of the `UICollectionViewCell` and I get errors as:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 7}'

I am stuck and unable to understand why this happens and how to solve this. Please help me find a solution for the same. Thank you.

In case you want to have a look at the layout file I used, please have a look here:

```
import UIKit

protocol PinterestLayoutDelegate: class {
    // 1. Method to ask the delegate for the height of the image
    func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat
}

class PinterestLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    //1. Pinterest Layout Delegate
    weak var delegate: PinterestLayoutDelegate!

    //2. Configurable properties
    fileprivate var numberOfColumns = 2
    fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 3

    //3. Array to keep a cache of attributes.
    fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    //4. Content height and size
    fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

    fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return 0
        }
        let insets = collectionView.contentInset
        return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func prepare() {
        // 1. Only calculate once
        guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }
        // 2. Pre-Calculates the X Offset for every column and adds an array to increment the currently max Y Offset for each column
        let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
        var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
        for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
            xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
        }
        var column = 0
        var yOffset = [CGFloat](repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)

        // 3. Iterates through the list of items in the first section
        for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)

            // 4. Asks the delegate for the height of the picture and the annotation and calculates the cell frame.
            let photoHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath)
            let height = cellPadding * 2 + photoHeight
            let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)

            // 5. Creates an UICollectionViewLayoutItem with the frame and add it to the cache
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            cache.append(attributes)

            // 6. Updates the collection view content height
            contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
            yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height

            column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
        }
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
        for attributes in cache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cache[indexPath.item]
    }

}
```

I followed: https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func prepare() {
    // 1. Only calculate once
    guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
        return
    }
```

In this part delete `guard cache.isEmpty == true,`. It works.

```
extension CategoryPageVC: PinterestLayoutDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

let rate = self.categoryData[indexPath.item].image.size.width / self.collectionView.frame.size.width * 2
        return self.categoryData[indexPath.item].image.size.height / rate
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the height of the collection view cell is not correct. Even if all cells are deleted, it will have the same scrollable height it had in the beginning. What to do in this case? @codeByThey